# Tensorflow tf.function conditionals

Tags: python, tensorflow

It took me some time to pin down the problem. Here is is:

```py
class ComplicatedStuff:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = None

    def fun(self, val):
        self.result = val

@tf.function
def no_fun(x, blabla):
    s = ComplicatedStuff()  
    # s.do_this(blabla)
    # s.do_that(blabla)
    if x > .5:
        s.fun(2*x)
    else:
        s.fun(x)
    return s.result
    
no_fun(tf.constant(1.), ...)
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>
```

I would really expect to get `2.0` back instead of `1.0`. I figured out the reason is that the conditional is traced in both branches, and because I return a value using a side-effect in `s`, only the result of the second branch survives. The question is, how do I code around this limitation? Using return values would solve it, but it will definitely uglify the code because ComplicatedStuff wraps a bunch of intermediate results that I don't want to expose like that. Is there some better option?

The thing I came up with that more-or-less preserved the structure, is this hackery:

```py
class ComplicatedStuff(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.result = None

    def fun(self, val):
        self.result = val
        
    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        self[item] = value
    
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item.startswith("__") or item not in self:
            return super().__getattribute__(item)
        else:
            return self[item]
        
@tf.function
def no_fun(x, blabla):
    s = ComplicatedStuff()
    # s.do_this(blabla)
    # s.do_that(blabla)
    if x > .5:
        s.fun(2*x)
        s = s
    else:
        s.fun(x)
        s = s
    return s.result
    
no_fun(tf.constant(1.), ...)
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>
```

There must be a better option, right?

Comment: My solution has other poblems :-/ It's not usable because inheriting from `dict` messes up other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow automatically converts some `if` statements into [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) nodes in `tf.function`. This is called [Autograph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#conditionals).

Since that is not working here, we can do that ourselves:

```py
class ComplicatedStuff:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = None

    def fun(self, val):
        self.result = val

@tf.function
def no_fun(x, blabla):
    s = ComplicatedStuff()  
    # s.do_this(blabla)
    # s.do_that(blabla)

    x_tmp = tf.cond(x > .5, lambda: 2*x, lambda: x)
    s.fun(x_tmp)
    return s.result
    
no_fun(tf.constant(1.), ...)
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>

no_fun(tf.constant(0.23), ...)
>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.23>
```

As mentioned in the docs:

> [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) traces and adds both branches of the conditional to the graph,
> dynamically selecting a branch at execution time.

Comment: That's what I settled for too :)
There were other conditionals with only one branch. Had to pass in a boolean and muck up the code anyway :-/